# how to get text content of textEdit in gui

Tags: qt

I have created a gui for image acquisition. In the gui, there is a push button for image saving, and one `textEdit` (maybe a `lineText` can also be used) for receiving the input of image name defined by the user, which is to be used as the output name of the image. My question is: 1) how to get the input text of the `textEdit`?, and then 2) to save the image (`QImage`) in .jpeg format to the current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ jingweimo, I had a similar problem, I hope that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600982/qlabel-not-showing-images-using-qtoolbutton) could be suitable for your case. 
For getting the input image name you only need to:

```
ui->labelCroppedA->setPixmap(
   QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(cdir + "/" + croppedFilenamesA[croppedIndexA])));
                                    ^ add directory separator
```

Also for saving the image in `jpeg` format (or additional format) you could use a specific function `QImageWriter::supportedImageFormats()` which has a lot of formats you may choose from and you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095133/how-to-use-qcombobox-to-choose-how-to-save-the-format-of-a-qimage) from my previous question or below:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView{scene};
    scene->addRect(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100), QPen(Qt::red), QBrush(Qt::blue));
    scene->addEllipse(QRectF(40, 30, 100, 100), QPen(Qt::green), QBrush(Qt::gray));
    QComboBox *combo_formats = new QComboBox;
    for(const QByteArray & format : QImageWriter::supportedImageFormats()){
        combo_formats->addItem(format);
    }
    QPushButton *save_button = new QPushButton{"Save"};
    QObject::connect(save_button, &QPushButton::clicked,[view, combo_formats](){
       QPixmap pixmap = view->grab();
       QString filename = QString("%1.%2").arg("image").arg(combo_formats->currentText());
       pixmap.save(filename);
    });
    QMainWindow w;
    QWidget *central_widget = new QWidget;
    w.setCentralWidget(central_widget);
    QFormLayout *lay = new QFormLayout{central_widget};
    lay->addRow(view);
    lay->addRow("Select Format:", combo_formats);
    lay->addRow(save_button);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I hope this could be useful for your project